# Deleting all files except the most 3 recent in a folder and sub folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, subdirectory

To clean up our back-ups folder I have written a short batch file that will be run Via task scheduler to periodically clear all files except the 3 most recent copies.

Currently I have the following

```
for /f "skip=3 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d *.sqb ^| findstr /r /c:"LOG_.*"') do @del "%%F"
```

This will work for the files inside the folder with the batch file, however I would like to run it from a higher level to check all the backups, I have tried the /s command but these only leaves the 3 most recent out of ALL folders where as I need to keep the 3 most recent files in EVERY folder and subfolder

Comment: I suggest to wrap a `for /R /D` around which enumerates a directory recursively...

Answer (score 1):

Loop recursively by directories first:

```dos
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
    for /f "skip=3 eol=* delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d "%%a\*LOG*.sqb"') do (
        del "%%~fb"
    )
) 2>nul
```

Comment: Seems to be running into an error where its looking for one of the files in the sub directory in the main directory.

Comment: Yep, see the updated code, now the full path is used